# SPSS: How to create sequential variables

Tags: spss

Im very new to SPSS and I am to create variables with names that are similar.
Specifically, i have to create variables:

1. Visit1_microbe1_test1
2. Visit1_microbe1_result1
3. Visit1_microbe1_test2
4. Visit1_microbe1_result2
5. ...
6. Visit1_microbe2_test1
7. Visit1_microbe2_result1
8. Visit1_microbe2_test2
9. Visit1_microbe2_result2
10. ...
11. Visit3_microbe1_test1
12. Visit3_microbe1_result1
13. ...
14. Visit3_microbe10_test5
15. Visit3_microbe10_result5

I can do it manually but it will take a lot of time, please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various potential commands in `SPSS` to deal with repetive task such as this.

See for example:

- [`DO REPEAT`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_do_repeat_examples.htm?lang=en)
- [`VECTOR / LOOP`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_vector_outside_loop.htm?lang=en)

In this instance [`SPSS's Macro language`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_define_list-processing_loop.htm?lang=en) is perhaps most apt.

So you may do something like this (This isn't an attempt to answer your exact specific requirement but enough to give you soemthing to work with to adapt to your needs):

```
DEFINE !CreateNewVars ().
!DO !i = 1 !TO 5
    !DO !j = 2 !TO 10
    COMPUTE !CONCAT("Q", !i,"_X", !j)=1.
    !DOEND
!DOEND
!ENDDEFINE.

!CreateNewVars.
```

Comment: Can I have a follow-up question on this?
How to add value option for each variables?

Comment: I have defaulted to each variable equating one but I'm sure that is not what you are going to want to do so you can assign as you see fit.